# Breadth-First Search on Pacman maze

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, pacman

I'm currently building a program that eats all the food on a pacman maze. However, my program is called everytime Pacman makes a new move, so no memory will be saved when the program ends, and it only returns a move: L,R,U or Down. I'm new on AI and also new on java programming. I know, from searching on Google, that the best way to do it is with BFS. The question is: how do I do this? Do I have to create a LinkedList for every position that I visit, containing the path that took me there? por example: UULLDDLRRL.

Another doubt that I have is, how do I make pacman search for the nearest food?

here is my code, I deleted the input part of the code, that doesn't matter for my question. I'm saving the map from Pacman on a char[][].

```
class position{
    int pX=0;
    int pY=0;
    char direction;
    Boolean visited = false;


position(int pY, int pX, char direcao,Boolean visited)
{
    this.pX=pX;
    this.pY=pY;
    this.direcao=direction;
    this.direction=direction;
}

position()
{
    pX=0;
    pY=0;
    direction='N';
    visited=false;
}
```

}

```
    position current = new position(pacmany,pacmanx,'N',false);
    LinkedList<position> analise = new LinkedList<position>();

    analise.addLast(current);

    while(!analise.isEmpty())
    {
        if(m[current.pY-1][current.pX]!='#')
        {
            analise.addLast(new position(current.pY-1,current.pX,'U',false));
        }

        if(m[current.pY][current.pX+1]!='#')
        {
            analise.addLast(new position(current.pY,current.pX+1,'R',false));
        }

        if(m[current.pY+1][current.pX]!='#')
        {
            analise.addLast(new position(current.pY+1,current.pX,'D',false));
        }

        if(m[current.pY][current.pX-1]!='#')
        {
            analise.addLast(new position(current.pY,current.pX-1,'L',false));
        }

        analise.get(i).visited=true;
        current=analise.get(i);
        analise.remove();
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: *how do I do this?* by starting to write something. At the beginning, it does not matter whether you use a `List` or `Collection` or an array. Get prototyping. Also, looking for "the next food" is just a special case of Breadth-First Search. If you have implemented BFS, you should be able to change the goal-condition pretty easily.

Comment: I have coded something but I'm having problems implementing the BFS. updated the post

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Are you asking "how do I find the closest food" or "how do I find the shortest path that includes all food". The first is fairly trivial and the second is thought to be impossible to do efficiently (though this is yet to be proven mathematically - search for NP-complete or travelling salesman problem on google if you're interested in the details) .

Comment: All my program as to do is return to a server the next move to the pacman. In the end, the point is to catch all the food, yes. but, I don't have to find the shortest path to eat all the food 'cause all my code as to do is find the next food, get there and then return the first move it made to get there. examle: imagine I find the nearest food with this path: ULLLUDDRRULD. All my code has to do is return U. My problem is: how do I search for the nearst food and how do I save all the moves that got me there so that I can return the first direction that I took